# Vue/Typescript/Jest - Jest Unit Test SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, babel-jest

I am running a Vue/Typescript/Vuetify project(Created with vue cli 3). For unit testing I am using Jest. I upgraded to a newer version of Vuetify(1.3.1). Since the upgrade I get an error when running my Jest tests:

```
location_to_project\node_modules\vuetify\lib\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import Vuetify from './components/Vuetify';
                                                                                        ^^^^^^
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      1 | import Vue from 'vue'
      2 | // @ts-ignore
    > 3 | import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
        | ^
      4 | import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'
      5 |
      6 | Vue.use(Vuetify, {

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:4    7)
03:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/plugins/vuetify.ts:3:1)
```

#### Versions and Environment

`Vuetify: 1.3.0`
`Vue: 2.5.17`

#### Previously worked in:

`Vuetify: 1.2.10`
`Vue: 2.5.17`

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
        [
            "@vue/app",
            {
                useBuiltIns: "entry"
            }
    ],
  ],
};
```

tsConfig Compiler:

`"target": "esnext"`

`"module": "esnext"`

Comment: I get the same error when I try the import your way in version `1.1.13`.  I'm not sure why this had ever worked before.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered same problem.
but, I could workaround by below.

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
```

just remove "/lib"

Comment: When I followed your advice, I got rid of the error regarding that line. However, an error was detected on the next line: `import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'`.
Also, it seams a bit scary to make changes in Vuetify package...

Comment: Why do you need to import style(like css)?
How about removing it?

Comment: Thank you! I found the root of the problem: the component, which I was testing, imported an event bus from `main.js` and it was the Vuetify import _in this `main.js` file_, which created the problem. I restructured my code so that the component does not import from `main.js` any more

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (odd) issue. Found an answer in [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1879) thread.

The solution was to run

```
npx jest --clearCache
```

and the tests worked after that.